# Trying to understand AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sum'

Tags: python, pandas

was wondering if anyone can help me understand why the error keeps coming up:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sum'"

```
final5UK.head(5)/UKyear['Mortality'].sum()
```

[Code   Mortality      Code Proportion
C546    38945          C546 ...%
C367    37687          C367 ...%
C436    27857          C436 ...%
C357    24868          C357 ...%
C34     17849          C34  ...%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU6mr.png)
trying to divide above table by a total figure from before to gain a new table with the individual proportions in % for each of the 5 listed above.

Thanks

Comment: Hi could you provide the result of print(UKyear['Mortality']) please?

Comment: print("Total number of deaths in UK is:", UK2010year['Mortality1'].sum()) gives 346578

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(final5UK.head(5)/UKyear['Mortality']).sum()
```

You were calling `.sum()` on the second part, which is just an `integer`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is returning a total number instead of 5 separate numbers I was expecting in a new table. Any tips on how to modify to get 5 individual proportions instead of 1 total?Thanks

Comment: remove the sum? what are the 5 separate numbers meant to be?